# Drupal conditional field display in content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am busy developing a job board. I am using drop jobs and recruiter distributions as a guide. my Q: In recruiter you can select the application method, based on that selection it will show the next field.

For example: you select application method: email link -> it displays a field called email address link

OR

when you select use built in application system it should show a field for additional email notification.

How can I do this purely in creating a content type? I know they did it somehow but I don't know how.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into a module like: [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)